# Was trying to get the Data from the API Endpoints and Insert into Salesforce Org

Tags: apex, rest-api, future, developer, asynchronous

I am new to the Salesforce Developer and was trying to do something where I was trying to fetch the data from the API endpoints and Insert into my Object of salesforce Org.

Using the Future Asynchronous method I tried solving the scenario but its shows me with Status Code =429 (To many Bad Request). IF anyone can please help me to understand how to solve this problem in better way.

````
    
    @future(Callout=true)
    public static void CreateEmployeeByRest(){
    
        Http obj = new Http();  //create http obj
        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        req.setEndpoint('http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees');   
        req.setMethod('GET');

        HttpResponse res = obj.send(req); 
        
        system.debug(res.getStatusCode());
        if(res.getStatusCode() == 200){
            Map<String, object> results = (Map<String, object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());  // string->object
            List<object> resData = (List<object>)results.get('data');
            List<Employee__c> emp = new List<Employee__c>();
             for(object  empData : resData){
                Map<String, Object> empRecord = (Map<String, Object>)empData;
                 Employee__c e = new Employee__c
                                 (
                                     Name = (String)empRecord.get('employee_name'),
                                     Employee_Age__c = (integer)empRecord.get('employee_age'),
                                     Employee_Salary__c = (integer)empRecord.get('employee_salary')
                                 );
                 emp.add(e);
                 system.debug(empRecord.get('employee_name'));
            }
            insert emp;
        }
    
    }
       
}```


This is the code I Tried with.
````

Comment: The API itself is not working http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees, Try with an API that works. The code looks ok to me

Comment: The API Works but gives the 429 status code when there are too many requests